# module not found , falls outside of src directory error event though the folder is inside of src directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, solidity

i am importing the abi of smart contract inside one component in react js. and this error is coming up. although the contract abi "artifacts" folder is inside of the src directory. how is this error coming up possible?

```
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../../../../artifacts/contracts/cont.sol/VerifySig.json which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

Comment: Can you paste your import statement?

Comment: the import issue has resolved, i think the app is not refreshing on changes to the component